# Custom delegate method is calling

Tags: swift, custom-cell

```
import UIKit
protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
func liked(dataDict:NSDictionary,index:NSInteger)
}
class NameImageTextCell: UITableViewCell,UIActionSheetDelegate {
weak var delegateCell: CustomCellDelegate?
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
      if delegateCell==nil{
            delegateCell?.liked(dataDict: dataNodeDict, index: ItemIndex)
        }    
  }
}




////////
 class 
 FanWallVC:UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,
 CustomCellDelegate {
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
 let objNameImageTextCell = NameImageTextCell()
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "NameImageTextCell", bundle: nil), 
  forCellReuseIdentifier: "NameImageTextCell")
    objNameImageTextCell.delegateCell=self
   }
  func liked(dataDict: NSDictionary, index: NSInteger) {
   print("Called")
   }
  }
```

When i Click on IBAction(btnAction) in NameImageTextCell, delegateCell is nil,
So liked method is not getting call.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your code correctly. You need at least four spaces at the beginning of each line of code to make the code formatter kick in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should call:

```
objNameImageTextCell.delegateCell = self
```

in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

}
```

so it should look somthing like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NameImageTextCell", for: indexPath) as! NameImageTextCell

        cell.delegateCell = self
        //other cell customization

        return cell

    }
```

Comment: called in viewdidload.

Comment: @PintuRajput yes you're calling it in ViewDidLoad but it's not right because you are setting it for objNameImageTextCell let constant. And objNameImageTextCell is NOT the object generated by table view to show you on screen. It's just a cell you created and it sits somewhere in the heap. But never will be shown to the user. Table view dequeuing objects by it self and asks you to configure it in the method I've posted above.

Comment: also called in cellforRowAtIndexPath like

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NameImageTextCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! NameImageTextCell
        
        cell.delegateCell=self
        return cell
    }

Then crashes With
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @PintuRajput It's probably because it don't see cell with "NameImageTextCell" reuse identifier. Are you using xib file with cell?

Comment: @PintuRajput Great! :)

Comment: @PintuRajput if u'll have a time then I recommend you to watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78LWmmDxr4k there's a super cool explanation about dequeuing and all table view stuff

Comment: Thanks @Alex Shubin